# Spark regression only working with one feature

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have some data (~1 MB) on customers of a service provider. I'm trying to predict using Spark (PySpark on Databricks) if they will end their subscription (churn) based on a few features.

##### One-Feature Model

To start, I tried with only one feature and saw a successful training:

```python
# Create vector assembler to merge independent features (in this case just one) into one feature as a list
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['MonthlyCharges'], outputCol='Charges')

# Create a logistic regressor instance to take in this list ('Charges') and use churn labels
lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='Charges', labelCol='Churn_indexed')

# Select the two relevant columns an put in a new dataframe
# NOTE: Is this actually hurting performance by using extra memory? 
#       I wasn't sure if it would expedite the vector assembler transformation
relevant = df_num.select(['MonthlyCharges', 'Churn_indexed'])

# Transform the data using the Assembler and then dump the unwanted column ('Monthly Charges)
# NOTE: Is this selection also not necessary because 'lr' already knows which feature column to use?
curr = vectorAssembler2.transform(relevant).select(['Charges', 'Churn_indexed']) 

# Create train/test split
train2, test2 = curr.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=42)

# Fit the model
model = lr.fit(train2)
```

##### Two-Feature Model

However, when I try to use **two** independent features, I am getting an error

```python
vectorAssembler2 = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges'], outputCol='Charges')
lr2 = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='Charges', labelCol='Churn_indexed')

relevant = df_num.select(['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'Churn_indexed'])
curr = vectorAssembler2.transform(relevant).select(['Charges', 'Churn_indexed']) 

train2, test2 = curr.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=42)
model = lr2.fit(train2)
```

##### Error

Here is the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 29) (ip-10-172-254-69.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(VectorAssembler$$Lambda$5900/1716232969: (struct&lt;MonthlyCharges:double,TotalCharges:double&gt;) =&gt; struct&lt;type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array&lt;int&gt;,values:array&lt;double&gt;&gt;)
```

And expanding it shows this error:

```python
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1815097094215178> in <module>
     11 curr.show()
     12 
---> 13 model = lr.fit(train2)

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/MLWorkloadsInstrumentation/_pyspark.py in patched_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     28             call_succeeded = False
     29             try:
---> 30                 result = original_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     31                 call_succeeded = True
     32                 return result

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    159                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160             else:
--> 161                 return self._fit(dataset)
    162         else:
    163             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 335         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    336         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    337         return self._copyValues(model)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    330         """
    331         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 332         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1465.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 29) (ip-10-172-254-69.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(VectorAssembler$$Lambda$5900/1716232969: (struct<MonthlyCharges:double,TotalCharges:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate$(TraversableOnce.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$3(RDD.scala:1240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$5(RDD.scala:1241)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:791)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1(VectorAssembler.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1$adapted(VectorAssembler.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.$anonfun$transform$6(VectorAssembler.scala:144)
    ... 41 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2712)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2446)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2429)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2541)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1232)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Summarizer$.getClassificationSummarizers(Summarizer.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.$anonfun$train$1(LogisticRegression.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:284)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(VectorAssembler$$Lambda$5900/1716232969: (struct<MonthlyCharges:double,TotalCharges:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate$(TraversableOnce.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$3(RDD.scala:1240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$5(RDD.scala:1241)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:791)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1(VectorAssembler.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1$adapted(VectorAssembler.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.$anonfun$transform$6(VectorAssembler.scala:144)
    ... 41 more
```

Does anyone know what is causing this behavior? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

##### Extra info:

- 15 GB, 2-Core Cluster
- DBR 8.3
- Spark 3.1.1
- Scala 2.12

## EDITS:

1. The data is customer churn data for a phone company. See here:

https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn

To test what the issue was, I used only one feature (monthly charges). Here is a screenshot of the data (charges having been vectorized)

[image]

I then added total charges as well, which gave me an error just like when I used all features. Here is what the data looked like using monthly **and** total charges:

[image]

2. Added the complete error!

---

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you are using? If it's private, you can anonymize it

Comment: Furthermore, what does the error say after the line `Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps`? It should say something like `but got ...`

Comment: Hi Ric S - I added the information, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error is because your data contains null values

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
> removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".

This is the count of null values of the data you shared from Kaggle

```
df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv('WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv')
print({col:df.filter(df[col].cast('float').isNull()).count() for col in ['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges']})

# {'MonthlyCharges': 0, 'TotalCharges': 11}
```

means that when your model only used `MonthlyCharges`, it worked fine because there was no null values. But when you included `TotalCharges` and some of the null values were in the training set, it threw the above error.

Try filling null values with zeros using `.fillna(0)`

```
relevant = df_num.select(['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'Churn_indexed']).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hi AdibP, it looks like you are right, but I don't know why. I loaded the data into a df called `df`, but then ran `df = df.na.drop()` which should've gotten rid of these values, no? `df_ind` then converts the categorical data into numerical, and then `df_num` simply isolates all of the numerical data into one df. Even after running the `.fillna(0)` line you provided, the `relevant` df _still_ says that it has 11 NaNs/nulls in the TotalCharges column, **but** it did end up training, so I guess this is solved. Thanks for the help!